# Select date that's in given date's interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of dates, and want to select dates that are in 1,5 hour interval of given date.
For example:

```
-- '2013-06-11 18:40' is the given date, and I want all dates that are 
-- inside +/- 1.5 hour interval
SELECT datum 
FROM table 
WHERE date(datum) > date( date_sub( '2013-06-11 18:40', interval 1.5 hour ) )
AND date(datum) < date( date_add( '2013-06-11 18:40', interval 1.5 hour ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MySQL `date` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) takes the `date` part of a `datetime`.  That's not advisable when you're looking for a 3 hour interval :)

Try:

```
WHERE datum between date_sub( '2013-06-11 18:40', interval 90 minute) and
    date_add( '2013-06-11 18:40', interval 90 minute)
```

Comment: Good point. Plus non-integer hours don't work: 18:40 + 1.5 HOUR in MySQL gives 20:40 instead of 20:10.

Comment: @Andomar thanks for the answer, this actually works, just edit the answer to `interval 90 minute` because `interval 1.5 hour` is rounded to 2 hours; so I can make it accepted answer!

Comment: @jOpacic: Done, I've voted for user4035 who noticed that `1.5 hour` doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I used integer minutes instead of hours plus removed DATE function as Andomar suggested:

```
SELECT datum 
FROM table 
WHERE 
datum > date( date_sub( '2013-06-11 18:40', interval 90 MINUTE ) )
AND 
datum < date( date_add( '2013-06-11 18:40', interval 90 MINUTE ) )
```